# FFmpegMediaPlayer crash when changing data source

Tags: android

Using https://github.com/wseemann/FFmpegMediaPlayer works great when I set it up and load data source.

Problem is when I want to switch data source, I get this crash error:

> 06-29 12:34:48.540 30538-30576/com.sdi.enhance A/libc: invalid
>   pthread_t 0x73756f69726176 passed to libc
>
> 06-29 12:34:48.542 30538-30576/com.sdi.enhance A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6
>   in tid 30576 (Timer-0)

Here is sample code:

```
play(url) {
    mediaPlayer = new FFmpegMediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
    mediaPlayer.prepare();
    mediaPlayer.start();
}

stop() {
    if (mediaPlayer != null) {
        mediaPlayer.stop();
        mediaPlayer.release();
        mediaPlayer = null;
    }
}

run() {
    loop every 10 seconds {
         stop();
         play(...);
    }
}
```

I also tried to init the player one time, and then call reset() after stop(), but getting similar libc error.

Comment: Ok its seem library issue https://github.com/wseemann/FFmpegMediaPlayer/issues/105